# based on each car animation

Tags: texture-baking

I'm finding it difficult to achieve car

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could unwrap your object so that the faces do a straight UV (here I've used *Follow Active Quads*):

[image]

Give it this node setup with a *Gradient* plugged into a *ColorRamp* and with the *Mapping* location value set to a value that makes it black:

[image]

Keyframe the *Mapping* location so that the light moves forward:

[image]